# Long compile and install time for fetching HTML

Tags: java, android

Its taking too long to compile the code (around 5mins +, only for this app).
Also when it's finally done, complete HTML is not displayed in the logcat! Only partial.
Can you guys please point out what's wrong with the code?
Is it because of "InputStream" reading character by character (as the HTML is huge)?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = task.execute("http://www.amazon.com").get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("Result",result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The more system calls you make like that, the worse your performance.  You should be reading in multiple kilobytes at a time, not characters.  If you need to loop over it one at a time, do that afterwards.

Also, use a StringBuilder!!!!  + on a string is HIGHLY inefficient.  For every character you make a new String object.  StringBuilder avoids that.

Comment: Thanks man, i had that doubt regarding my ipstream. So how should read multiple KB at a time?